# Jquery Toggle Not Working In Live Website

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make toggle a class with social buttons with jquery but somehow it's not working when I add it to my website, in JsFiddle is working great though.

Heres the **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhsajfts/)** and here's my **[website](http://tv.pulseframe.com/internet/o-que-nao-fazer-numa-mota-de-cross/)** so you can check that's not working there.
it's below the video.

I don't know what am I doing wrong, I've added this to my header file:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#share-stuff" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

</script>
```

and this where I want the class to appear:

```
<div id="clickme">
    Partilhar
</div>
<div id="share-stuff"> <!-- social share buttons -->
    <ul class="crafty-social-buttons-list">
        <li><a class="crafty-social-button csb-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" width="38" height="38" src="../tv/wp-content/themes/trademark/share-buttons/facebook.png"></a></li>
        <li><a class="crafty-social-button csb-google" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><img title="Google" alt="Google" width="38" height="38" src="../tv/wp-content/themes/trademark/share-buttons/google.png"></a></li>
        <li><a class="crafty-social-button csb-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" width="38" height="38" src="../tv/wp-content/themes/trademark/share-buttons/twitter.png"></a></li>
        <li><a class="crafty-social-button csb-reddit" href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><img title="Reddit" alt="Reddit" width="38" height="38" src="../tv/wp-content/themes/trademark/share-buttons/reddit.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also how can I make it to start closed instead open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Also to close `share-stuff` onload, hide it first:

http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/omeedr9z/

```
// $(document).ready equivalent
$(function(){
    // collapse share-stuff onload by using .hide() 
    $( "#share-stuff" ).hide();

    $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
      $( "#share-stuff" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind clickme item before it is rendered on the dom. Move your jquery codes to the end of the document. and preferably wrap them with document ready code like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// your jquery codes

});
```

Comment: @Dom He is binding click event on the header of the document. Thats why it is workin in the fiddle but not in his project. and what is OP?

Comment: Sorry, read the last question only in that question. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// your jquery codes

});
```

You have to wrap jquery in above manner, and seems to there is an error on the page, please check both.